# How to replace the list of decimal numbers in a string with another list of decimal numbers?

Tags: python-re

I need to replace the list of decimal numbers in a string with another list of decimal numbers. The following is a first try, that changes all decimal numbers with the same decimal number:

```
>>> re.sub (r"[-+]?\d*\.\d+f?", "1.0", "hello 1.2 3.4")
'hello 1.0 1.0'
```

I  need something like `my_replace` below:

```
>>> my_replace (r"[-+]?\d*\.\d+f?", [1.0, 2.0], "hello 1.2 3.4")
'hello 1.0 2.0'
```

How can i implement `my_replace` with python's re module?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that you can use a list as replacement variables and iterate over them. So it can't handle *unhashable* objects (this is what python is complaining about). But it wouln'd be able to handle numerics as well (so it would need a list of strings but this is obviously hypothetical xD)

I would just loop over the string and compy everything that is not a decimal number to a new string and replacing the decimal numbers found.

```py
text = "hello 1.2 3.4 don't replace an integer: 9 but this decimal number is too much: 0.0 (so use last value!)"
new_numbers = [42, 3.1415926535]

new_text = ''
idx_last = 0
for i, tx in enumerate(re.finditer(r'[-+]?\d*\.\d+f?', text)):
    # add text before the number
    new_text += tx.string[idx_last:tx.start()]
    # add new number (but ensure that your are not overflowing the list of new numbers
    new_text += str(new_numbers[min([i, len(new_numbers) - 1])])
    # update text index
    idx_last = tx.end()
# update remaining part of the text
new_text += text[idx_last:]
```

> "hello 42 3.1415926535 don't replace an integer: 9 but this decimal number is too much: 3.1415926535 (so use last value!)"

Wrap it to a function and you have your `my_replace()` =)